# Getting a custom fieldtype working in Matrix

Tags: matrix

I've recently updated EE to 2.5.5 and Matrix to 2.5.3, but now one of out in-house addons is broken. The addon is a custom fieldtype designed to be included in a Matrix field, but this now causes the publish page to turn blank. This is the only scenario in which this occurs; Matrix plays nicely with everything else, and our addon doesn't break anything when not included in a Matrix field.

I've tested this with a locally hosted version of EE 2.5.3, and got a PHP error rather than a blank page:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Content_publish::$tools_model

Filename: custom_fieldtype/ft.custom_fieldtype.php

Line Number: 271

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_upload_preferences() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\EE\system\expressionengine\third_party\custom_fieldtype\ft.custom_fieldtype.php on line 271

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Tool Model isn't being loaded before calling its property. Try by putting this line of code above the line number 271:

```
$this->EE->load->model('tools_model');
```

Comment: Thank you! It took two weeks just to get that error message.

Comment: Just ran into more problems in the code - turns out 'tools_model' is deprecated. I'm opening up a new question to fix this.